# how to set the value of an html input field from a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set the value of an input field:

```
<input type="text" name="AMOUNT" value=getQueryVariable('amount'); >
```

from a javascript function:

```
  function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  } 
  alert('Query Variable ' + variable + ' not found');
}
```

My code is generating the following as the value of the field: "getQueryVariable('amount');" which is exactly what I wrote as the value (not calling the javascript function).

How can I get it to call the js function and place its result in the value field?

Thank you

Comment: Try adding double quotes around `value="getQueryVariable('amount');"`

Comment: @VPK is it working with double quotes. check it first.

Comment: @amit I did not tried it, that's why I asked OP to give it a try as I think it would be a possible error.

Comment: Seriously, I don't think you can execute a function inside 'value' because 'value' is not an event. If you add the double quotes, the quoted string will just be copied to the textbox.

Comment: yes write you can't execute a function inside value.

Comment: @maha You need to set the value through script

Comment: @amit & ChongLipPhang you both are right, I just checked it's not working as mentioned by ChongLipPhang.

Comment: where can I call getQueryVariable() to execute it as soon as the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside the if condition, change the return to this:

```
document.getElementsByName("AMOUNT")[0].value = pair[1];
```

Comment: and then where do I call getQueryVariable()?

Comment: you should put it in a script tag after the input element in the document <script> getQueryVariable('amount'); </script>  or use the onload function: <body onload='getQueryVariable("amount")'>...  Basically put it after the input element so it can be found by the getElementsByName.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. The onlooad function worked. But, actually I have 2 parameters which I would like to assign to input field values. So, how would I go around implementing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute a function inside the 'value' attribute because 'value' is not an event. If you add the double quotes, the quoted string will just be copied to the textbox.

You can do something like:

```
<script>
   document.getElementsByName('AMOUNT')[0].value = getQueryVariable('amount');
</script>
```